# Displaying Sharepoint 2010 Webparts in remote Portals

Tags: sharepoint-2010, liferay, web-parts

we currently have the need to display Webparts of a Sharepoint 2007 instance in another Portal (Liferay). I'm not familiar with Sharepoint. After some searching, I wasn't able to find a satisfiing answer. For Sharepoint 2007 there was announced the WSRP Toolkit (Webservices For Remote Portlets). http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WSRPToolkit

- Does anyone know if the Toolkit still works somehow the 2010 Version of Sharepoint (I failed when I tried)
- Is there maybe a way to access a single Webpart by URL (-parameters)
- Does anyone know another way to solve the Problem of displaying webparts in other Portals?

Thanks for you attention,
Andreas